# What is the best way to globally change the color of the ink in all paper elements used on my site?

Tags: css, components, polymer, material-design

The notes in the component html file say:

```
To change the ink color:

.pink paper-tab::shadow #ink {
  color: #ff4081;
}
```

I want to do it globally, so I tried the above example (without the .pink class) in my main site.css and it had no effect.  I also tried the following without any luck.

```
#ink { color: green !important }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `/deep/` combinator

```
<style>
  html /deep/ #ink {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Rob's solution didn't work in my setup. I am using WebStorm and LESS.

I was able to use the following to great effect though:

```
::shadow {
    //this changes the lines on paper-tabs and the radios on a paper-radio-buttons
    #selectionBar, #onRadio { 
        background-color: green;
    }
    //this changes the "ink" on all ripple effects
    #ink {
        color: green;
    }
}
```